# How to download file from API (by setting Accept header of request)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest

I have an API server, which can reply to me with different formats of data. I can control this via 'Accept' header.

I need to download .csv file. To do it I must make a GET query with

```
Accept: 'text/csv'
```

header

How can I do it?

I know that I can do a XHR query, but in this case I don't know how to save data to file. Or I can do a window.open, but in this case I don't know how to set Accept header (and someone tell that it is impossible).

Comment: What does the Accept header do with downloading? The server should respond with a `Content-Disposition` header.

Comment: Using ```Accept``` header means your client can understand ```text/csv``` responses. But to download your file the server will send you the file for example in node.js (express framework) I can do ```res.send(csvFile)``` to receive data but ```res.download(csvFile)``` to ask for the user to download (or not) the file.

Comment: I need some way to show server (and this way must not be a parametr) that I need reply in text/csv format, not in application/json (as default). I think good way is send to server request with only 
    Accept: "text/csv"
in headers, but when I try this (by XHR) "text/csv" was added to browser std string. Now I configured server to search "text/csv" in Accept header and than send me data in this format.


No, I don't use node